# Sorting multidimensional array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array 
               ( [name] => Jonah 
                 [age] => 27 )
        [1] => Array 
               ( [name] => Bianca 
                 [age] => 32 )
      )
```

Is it possible to sort the sub-array values in `[age]` into some sort of order, such as lowest to highest or vice versa?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using [`usort`](http://php.net/usort):

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b)
{
    return $a['age'] - $b['age']; // sorts lowest to highest
});
```

Swap `$a` and `$b` in the function to reverse the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be possible with `bool usort ( array &$array , callback $cmp_function )`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Just define a callback that sorts by the [age] key of the value.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$ages = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
  $ages[] = $value;
}

array_multisort($values, SORT_ASC, $array);
```

Any way is good, but this is [the "PHP way"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php):

> **array_multisort()** can be used to sort several arrays at once, *or a multi-dimensional array by one or more dimensions*.